# Generate secure access token

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I'm using OAuth for authentication, what is the best way to generate a secure access token for a user? and should you store the access token in the database or generate a new one everytime it is request?

I'm using bearer token.

Answer (score 0):

access tokens do not need to be stored in a persistent storage (refresh tokens on the other hand usually do). A common scenario implemented in asp.net web API when using the `Microsoft.Asp.Identity` libs is that the access_token is generated upon request in the same manner a Cookie is send back to a client after successful login when using FormsAuthentication.

The access token is a serialized ClaimsPrincipal that is encrypted using the Asp.Net Machine Key and then Base64-ed.

More or less, each time the client makes a request to the API with an "Authorize" header present (something like
`Authorize: Bearer asdfdsgwe.......YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN........2334sdfs===`) the server needs only to get `Byte[]` from the base64-ed string then decrypt using the machine key and finally deserialize back to an IPrincipal. This process takes place early on in the lifecycle of the WebAPI and the `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` is populated.

That said the access_token itself contains all the necessary information to identify the current user without the need to go back to the Database.

**UPDATE** 
If you are not interested in using `Microsoft.Asp.Identity` to create access_tokens for you. Then I recommend using the [System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt Nuget Package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/) to roll your own implementation. Keep in mind that this is not an easy task. Also check out an excellent opensource reference implementation by thinktecture: [Thinktecture Identity Server v3](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v3)

Hope this helps.